# How to remove time portion from Nullable<DateTime> in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

Below is my LINQ

```
 IQueryable<ReportMapper> query;

                    query = (from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                             join d in entities.tTOCStructures on c.DocumentId equals d.DocumentID
                             join e in entities.tUsers on d.LastUpdatedBy equals e.UserUID
                             orderby d.CreatedOn descending
                             where
                              (docMode <= 0 || docModes.Contains(c.StatusId)) &&
                              d.FolderType == 2 && d.isDeleted == false && d.ClientID == clientId &&
                              (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.CreatedOn) >= startDate.Date && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.CreatedOn) <= endDate.Date) 
                             select new ReportMapper()
                             {
                                 DocumentName = d.DocumentName,
                                 AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate==null? (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.LastUpdatedOn)):  (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.AssignedDate)),
                                 ReviewStatus = c.tStatu.StatusName,
                                 ActionPerformedBy = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                             });
```

I need to export this data to excel. I am in need to remove the complete time portion from Assigned Date.

When I am using `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` it truncates the time to `00:00:00`

**But my need is to remove this portion.**

I tried the following:-

- `(EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.LastUpdatedOn)).Value.Date`
- `(EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.LastUpdatedOn).GetValueOrDefault().Date)`
- `(EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.LastUpdatedOn)).ToString().Date`

Export to Excel

```
   public void ExportToExcel()
    {
        ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
            var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
       fileName = "Document_Status_Report_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdHHmmss") + ".xlsx";
                worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(data, true);
 using (MemoryStream swObj = new MemoryStream())
            {
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "");
                excel.SaveAs(swObj);
                swObj.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
                return;
            }

    }
```

Comment: The property is `DateTime` which always has a 'time' component. Format it to a string if you only want the date portion

Comment: You can extract the Date part of a DateTime with `DateTime.Date`. The time part is available through `DateTime.TimeSpan`.

Comment: If you have problems with Excel, post the *relevant* code. Excel has no issues with time parts - it doesn't have date-only dates at all!. Dates in Excel are stored as a decimal offset from 1899-12-30. You can get that value with `DateTime.ToOADate`. It's a *lot* easier though to use a library like Epplus and let it do any conversions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, ExportToExccel() added

Comment: @Kgn-web that *is* Epplus. What is the problem then? If you used `.Date` the cell will contain `00:00:00` in the time part and the stored date value will have no seconds at all (ie no fractional part). The same holds with `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`. Did you use a date-only style for the column?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,How should  I do that??

Answer (score 1):

Use `.Value.Date` as you already have tried. *Never* strings.

Your issue is not the time part (@PanagiotisKanavos explained that) but the *format* applied to the cells in Excel. Just adjust this to display the date part only.

Comment: I have added my ExportToExcel() can you please tell where do I specify the dateformat

Comment: You can define a range in the worksheet - the (partial) column holding your date values - then set the Format property of that range.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` always has a time and you can not truncate or remove time from `Datetime`.If you want only date then suggest to add new string property in `ReportMapper` class and assign only Date string.As in below code I have assigned date in '`MM/dd/yyyy`' format to `AssignedDateString`.

```
IQueryable<ReportMapper> query;

                    query = (from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                             join d in entities.tTOCStructures on c.DocumentId equals d.DocumentID
                             join e in entities.tUsers on d.LastUpdatedBy equals e.UserUID
                             orderby d.CreatedOn descending
                             where
                              (docMode <= 0 || docModes.Contains(c.StatusId)) &&
                              d.FolderType == 2 && d.isDeleted == false && d.ClientID == clientId &&
                              (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.CreatedOn) >= startDate.Date && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.CreatedOn) <= endDate.Date) 
                             select new ReportMapper()
                             {
                                 DocumentName = d.DocumentName,
                                 AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate==null? (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.LastUpdatedOn)):  (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.AssignedDate)),
                                 ReviewStatus = c.tStatu.StatusName,
                                 ActionPerformedBy = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                                 AssignedDateString= c.AssignedDate==null? (d.LastUpdatedOn.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")):  (c.AssignedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")),
                             });
```

Comment: That format will cause problems in 90% of the world. There's no reason to use strings when talking about dates. If you do need to use strings, use an unambiguous format like ISO8601

Comment: Oh, and that format will *definitely* fail with Excel. Excel stores dates as a decimal number. `MM/dd/yyyy` will be treated as text at best, or interpreted as the wrong date

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agreed with you. In above code it's not necessary to use 'MM/dd/yyyy' only.I have just suggested how to format DateTime in particular date format.

Answer (score 0):

Best works for me was:-

```
manufactured_dates = detail.manufactured_date == null ? "" : ((DateTime)detail.manufactured_date).ToShortDateString()
```

Where I needed to get date into a string format out of a  `Nullable<DateTime>` in LINQ,
so as it was  `Nullable<DateTime>` 
I did

```
(DateTime)detail.manufactured_date
```

Then to extract just the date as a string out of Converted DateTime Value I applied
Value.ToShortDateString()

ie: `((DateTime)detail.manufactured_date).ToShortDateString()`

Or you can also do

```
((DateTime)detail.expiry_date).ToString("dd.MMM.yyyy")
```